# Multivariate Quadratic Equation

Tags: quadratic-forms, conic-sections

I know that the set of set of solutions of quadratic equation in two variables is a conic section. But what happens in higher dimensions (i.e, $n$ variables)?
I guess that we get some generalization of a conic section. Is that true? How to define conic section in higher dimension?

Thanks in advance!!

BTW, references will be appreciated :)

Comment: that might help http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/QuadricSurfaces.aspx